# Change color of all special char / using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the color of a special char / if it's present in any of the

tags.

This is what I have tried:

```js
var p = document.getElementsByClassName("items");
p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(/\.|:/g, function(match) {
  return "<i style=color:tomato;font-weight:bold>" + match + "</i>"
})
```

```html
<p class="i  items">A/B </p>
<p class="i  items">C</p>
<p class="i  items">C/E</p>
```

I get a console error:

```
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: @Konrad not really

Comment: are you trying to change the color of just the `/` or the entire line?

Comment: Just for the `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object. Arrays don't have innerHTML property. You have to loop through all elements of that object

```js
var ps = document.getElementsByClassName("items");
for (const p of ps) {
  p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(/\//g, function(match) {
    return "<i style=color:tomato;font-weight:bold>" + match + "</i>"
  })
}
```

```html
<p class="i  items">A/B </p>
<p class="i  items">C</p>
<p class="i  items">C/E</p>
```

Comment: I think my regex might be wrong as it doesn't change the color of /

Comment: Fixed the regex